# Прочитать файл и добавить элементы в новый массив в C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Всем привет. Извиянусь за мой руский язык. Я хочу объявить динамический массив, и следующая вещь - иметь возможность читать файл и добавлять элементы в массив Student. Вроде код компилирует, но результата не вижу. Ваше предложение приветствуется.

```
int main(int argc, char** agrv)
{
    if(argc < 2 || argc > 2)
    {
        cerr << "You have to provide a file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    string myFile = agrv[1];

    ifstream file(myFile.c_str());

    if (!file)
    {
        cerr << "Error, file do not exist" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Student students; // Declared in other file
    // File contains Number-String-String-String
    string number_student, name_student, surname_student, code_student;
    double number_file_student;


    // Declare an new array
     DynamicArray<Student>students; 

    while(file >>number_file_student >> name_student >> surname_student >> code_student)
    {
        students.add(student);
    }

        for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
        cout << students[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Вы не заполнили поля student - надо заполнить перед students.add(student);

Comment: Вероятно надо так  while(file >>student.number_file_student >> student.name_student ...) Предполагается, что student где-то определён

Comment: А вообще для совмистимости используйте std::vector<Student>, а не RAD Studio DynamicArray

Comment: Из кода неясно, что такое `student` (переменная не объявлена даже). И уж точно вы читаете данные, но в массив вносите что-то совсем другое.

Comment: ваши огрызки из кода не компилируются и не дадут ответить на ваш вопрос.